# Out of memory at line 12

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've developing a website in localhost. I'm using jquery, some javascripts, CSS and HTML.
When I try to load the site with IE, an error message pops up saying "Out of memory at line 12". I clicked "OK' and it continues working fine. The message however doesn't show up in Chrome or Firefox.
Can anyone tell me why is it so. How can i fix it??

Edit: I removed the jquery ui inclusion line and it stopped showing the errors. (Removed the line below)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My Javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {


        $("ul.blockeasing li.main").mouseover(function(){ //When mouse over ...
               //Following event is applied to the subnav itself (making height of subnav 60px)
              $(this).find('.subnav').stop().animate({height: '60px', opacity:'1'},{queue:false, duration:1500, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})
        });

        $("ul.blockeasing li.main").mouseout(function(){ //When mouse out ...
              //Following event is applied to the subnav itself (making height of subnav 0px)
              $(this).find('.subnav').stop().animate({height:'0px', opacity:'0'},{queue:false, duration:1600, easing: 'easeOutElastic'})
        });


        //menu itembackground color animation           
        $("ul.blockeasing li").hover(function() {
              $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#C13D93"}, 600);},
           function() {
              $(this).stop().animate({ backgroundColor: "#de93c3" }, 600);
        });

});
</script>
```

Comment: What code are you trying to execute, which version of IE?

Comment: Nothing important.. it's just this: <style type="text/css">

Comment: Am trying to execute PHP code. IE v 8.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, the best we can probably come up with is that you're running out of memory on line 12. But you probably know that already so it may be worth considering giving us a little _more_ information :-) Like, say, the first 20 lines of the file.

Comment: Well, something is happening in your code that causes IE to run out of memory while processing it. Without seeing the code, there are only two possible answers: Stop whatever it is you're doing wrong, or install more memory. We don't have magic crystal balls, so we don't know what's causing this problem. **Post your code or a link to the site in question.**

Comment: @deceze Here ya go: http://localhost/my_memory_consuming_site/ :)

Comment: @jensgram Hmm, I'm getting a different error there, but consistently in all browsers...

Comment: line 12 is actually commented out. Or m i mistaken??

Comment: @ptamzz, Please post the *JavaScript* code, not the *PHP* code.  The error is occurring in JavaScript.  If you can, isolate what file is causing the error, and post just that file.  If you can't do that, remove JavaScript files until the error goes away; the last removed script is (likely) causing the error, so post that.

Comment: thanks @strager. i'll try removing first before I post the js codes coz there are many.

Comment: @ptamzz, Can you point out what line 12 is?  Also, can you provide a live example of the site (even just the rendered output) or run your code under IE8's script debugger?

Comment: Well, I'm developing in localhost so Im not able to show you a live example. The code posted above is the source view from IE.

Comment: line 12 here seems to be <style type="text/css">

Comment: @ptamzz, The error occurs on line 12 of an *externally linked script*.  As I said, remove references to scripts until you remove the error, then post the beginning of the script which (likely) caused the error.

Comment: @strager.. i did that. It was the jquery-ui (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js) as mentioned in my post above. i removed it and the error was gone.

Comment: how can it be wrong??? I've also posted the javascripts i've used within my page.

Comment: @ptamzz, Try a non-minified version of jQuery UI.  Then report what line the error occurs on and what version of jQuery UI you are using.

Comment: I tried using the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js. The error still persist as line 12.

Comment: @ptamzz, Well, line 12 is a comment, so clearly it's not jQuery UI which is causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First off, it's impossible to tell without any source. "Out of memory" could be an infinite loop. I really don't know.

*But* you state that you're "*... trying to execute PHP code.*" In that case make sure that line 12 is really what you think it is. If you've got PHP and HTML in the same file remember that you're looking for line 12 **on the client** (i.e., in the rendered output), not in the PHP file.

---

**EDIT**
We don't need your PHP code. Actually we're only interested in the *rendered output* (i.e., the resulting mark-up - HTML & JavaScript - sent to the browser). *If* the error is caused by an included JS file, please post this file.

Furthermore, a few comments on your question is worth noting. Not least @strager's comment; remove JS inclusions until the error disappears. This will probably help you identify the cause.

Comment: Yes.. i did that. I removed the jquery ui inclusion line and the error doesnt popped up. Now I'd used the javascript code as posted.

Answer (score 2):

some other people, including MrBoJangles and this [guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501123/erorr-while-using-jquery-animate-out-of-memory-at-line-13)
have probably figured this problem out, and I can confirm from experience.  Make sure you're running compatible versions of JQuery & JQueryUI - ie just get the latest stable releases of both.  The issue I was having in IE8 was based on this compatibility issue - I was initially running JQuery 1.3.2, and I needed a newer version to work with my newer version of JQuery UI.

Comment: I agree with Jesse. I got the OutOfMemory exception when running JQuery 1.3 with JQuery 1.8.3.

Answer (score 1):

mostly this error is caused by infinite recursive function calls which deplete the browser stack giving 'Out of memory error'